# Integrating Gaussian type integrand

Tags: gaussian-integral

Any idea how to perform these two integrations?

1.
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{exp(-a x^2)}{x^2(x^2+\kappa^2)} dx
$$
2.
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{exp(-a x^2)}{(x^2+\kappa^2)} dx
$$
second integration is same as equation 1.42 of this [link](http://www.mhtlab.uwaterloo.ca/courses/me755/web_chap2.pdf)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am afraid that these integrals do not show explicit expression.

Considering the second one
$$I=\int \frac{e^{-a x^2}}{x^2+\kappa ^2}\,dx$$ let $x=\kappa y$ and $b=a \kappa ^2$ to make
$$I=\frac 1 \kappa \int \frac{e^{-b y^2}}{y^2+1}\,dy=\frac1 \kappa\int e^{-by^2}\Big[\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n y^{2n}\Big]\,dy$$
$$I=\frac1 \kappa\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n\int y^{2n}\, e^{-b y^2}\,dy=\frac1 \kappa\int  e^{-b y^2}\,dy+\frac1 \kappa\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n\int y^{2n}\, e^{-b y^2}\,dy$$ with
$$\int  e^{-b y^2}\,dy=\frac{\sqrt{\pi } }{2 \sqrt{b}}\,\text{erf}\left(\sqrt{b} y\right)$$
$$\int y^{2n}\, e^{-b y^2}\,dy=b^{-(n+\frac{1}{2})} \Gamma \left(n+\frac{1}{2},b y^2\right)$$

Comment: that's very useful; I was trying to get the answer as given in eq 1.42, in the following link,http://www.mhtlab.uwaterloo.ca/courses/me755/web_chap2.pdf, I have updated the question, as I found this later

Comment: @isoura. Your question was **not** about the definite integral but about th antiderivative. Please clarify.

Comment: Yeah, it is for the antiderivative only, but I'm trying to get the definite integral as well.